Determine if wifi password was incorrect on command line
I am writing a shell script (bash) to do some system configuration and one of the steps is entering a wifi SSID and password. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.
I then connect by creating an appropriate netplan file and running netplan apply.
At some point after this (given enough time to connect to the network) I want to notify the user of the connection status.
I'd like to be able to specifically tell them if the password was incorrect, but I can't figure out a way to determine this. All I know how to do is check for general connectivity by pinging one of my servers, but I want to be able to distinguish between an incorrect password vs. lack of connectivity.
Is there a way, after running netplan apply, to determine if the network connection could not be established due to an incorrect WiFi password?

Have you looked at the exit status of the netplan apply command? Does it exit with the same value for all kinds of failure, or could there perhaps be a specific value for wrong password?

@terdon AFAICT netplan apply only exits with a failure if the config file has a syntax error. The wifi connection happens asynchronously, I believe via wpa_supplicant, netplan only initiates it.

Likely not the best way, but I'll leave it here in case nothing better comes up; naively parsing iw should get you there:
iw dev wlo1 link | awk 'NR==1 && /^Connected/ {exit 0} {exit 1}'

(replacing wlo1 with the interface's name as reported by e.g. ip link).
Factoring it into a function:
function wlo1_is_connected() {
    iw dev wlo1 link | awk 'NR==1 && /^Connected/ {exit 0} {exit 1}'
}

You could then use the function something like this:
wlo1_is_connected
    && printf 'Connected\n'
    || printf 'Not connected\n'

Obviously replacing the printfs with something more useful, such as a new attempt to connect or some error handling.
